# Android app initialization sdk in application by useing ThreadPool

Tags: android

MyApplication App used too many other company's sdk and initialization in application,make app start very slow.
Is it okay to initialization sdk in application by useing ThreadPool?
Like:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
           @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       String processName = getCurProcessName(this);
       boolean defaultProcess = processName.equals("mypackage"); 
       if(defaultProcess){
           ExecutorService cachedThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                cachedThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      aSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                      bSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                      cSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                      dSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                      eSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                      fSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                      gSDK.init(MyApplication.this);
                    }
       }
    }
}
```

The functions which need these sdks,wont be called immediately.It is like in some activity,press a button to call a function which need these sdk or one of these sdk already initialized.

Comment: you should ask this question to people who wrote these SDKs: are they ready to be run in different `Thread` than UI? if yes then using `ExecuterService` is good approach

Comment: the functions which need these sdks,wont be called immediately.It is like in some activity,press a button to call a function which need these sdk initialized.

Comment: yeah, but this in fact doesn't matter in the topic of this question. real question is: are these SDKs are ready to be run in separated, dedicated `Thread`? or maybe they MUST be run in main UI `Thread` or have other limitations

Comment: thanks I'll try to confrim this. In my test this didnt cause crash,but I still not sure this is right.

Comment: I doubt that these SDKs needs UI `Thread`, properly written SDK-libs even should be inited and work in another `Thread`. so if everything is working fine with posted code then you can assume that you are good to go, but if you have access to authors od SDKs its worth asking if these tools depends on any android-specific behavior (like `Context`, threading, etc.)